# Uppercase the first letter in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, uppercase

Heres my data,

```
> data
   Manufacturers       Models
1   audi                RS5  
2   bmw                 M3  
3   cadillac            CTS-V  
4   lexus               ISF
```

And I would want to uppercase the first letter in the first column, like this:

```
> data
   Manufacturers       Models
1   Audi                RS5  
2   Bmw                 M3  
3   Cadillac            CTS-V  
4   Lexus               ISF
```

I would appreciate any help on this question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Taking the example from the documentation for `?toupper` and modifying it a bit:

```
capFirst <- function(s) {
    paste(toupper(substring(s, 1, 1)), substring(s, 2), sep = "")
}

data$Manufacturers <- capFirst(data$Manufacturers)
> data
#   Manufacturers Models
# 1          Audi    RS5
# 2           Bmw     M3
# 3      Cadillac  CTS-V
# 4         Lexus    ISF
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this so the first letter of each word (if each entry might be more than one word) is capitalized?  The other solutions on stack use apply and are too slow, I like this vectorized solution

Answer (score 7):

Or, taking an example from `?gsub`:

```
data$Manufacturers <- gsub("^(\\w)(\\w+)", "\\U\\1\\L\\2", 
  data$Manufacturers, perl = TRUE)

> data
>  Manufacturers Models
1          Audi    RS5
2           Bmw     M3
3      Cadillac  CTS-V
4         Lexus    ISF
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is pretty simple.

You can solve this problem by subsetting and upper-casing a string vector.

- Step1: `stringr::str_sub()` subsets a string vector. `str_sub(string,
  1, 1)` indicates the first letter. `str_sub(df, 1, 1)` returns a
  vector of the first letters.
- Step2: `stringr::str_to_upper()` turn the first letters into upper
  case.

```
# Load package
    library(tidyverse)

# Your data
    df <- tibble(Manufacturers = c("audi", "bmw", "cadillac", "lexus"),
             Models = c("RS5", "M3", "CTS-V", "ISF"))

# Solution
    str_sub(df$Manufacturers, 1, 1) <- str_sub(df$Manufacturers, 1, 1) %>% str_to_upper()
```