# How to substitute a lowercase letter after a hyphen with its uppercase

Tags: regex, r, substitution, uppercase

In my dataframe I have a column with the last names of parlement members in lowercase. I substituted the first letter with it's uppercase with (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16252918/2204410)):

```
# vector with names
lastname <- c("wortmann-kool", "mulder", "nistelrooij", "camp", "schaake", "veld", "lange", "oomen-ruijten")
# substituting first letter with uppercase
lastname <- gsub("^(\\w)(\\w+)", "\\U\\1\\L\\2", lastname, perl = TRUE)
```

As you can see, some name have hyphen to separate the two names of married women. How do I substitute the first letter after the hyphen with it's uppercase?

Comment: does it have to be in a single `gsub`? `gsub("-([a-z])", "-\\U\\1", gsub("^(\\w)(\\w+)", "\\U\\1\\L\\2", lastname, perl = TRUE))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not simply uppercase the first letter after a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)?

```
> lastname <- c("wortmann-kool", "mulder", "nistelrooij", "camp", "schaake", "veld", "lange", "oomen-ruijten")
> gsub("\\b(\\w)", "\\U\\1", lastname, perl = TRUE)
[1] "Wortmann-Kool" "Mulder"        "Nistelrooij"   "Camp"         
[5] "Schaake"       "Veld"          "Lange"         "Oomen-Ruijten"
>
```

---

Quoting from the [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html):

> For perl = TRUE only, it can also contain "\U" or "\L" to convert the
>   rest of the replacement to upper or lower case and "\E" to end case
>   conversion.

```
## capitalizing
txt <- "a test of capitalizing"
gsub("(\\w)(\\w*)", "\\U\\1\\L\\2", txt, perl=TRUE)
gsub("\\b(\\w)",    "\\U\\1",       txt, perl=TRUE)
```

Comment: Upvoting for compact and efficient. :)

Comment: Very nice. Is that option documented somewhere in R, or is the uppercasing `"\\U"` something that comes from the PCRE library and is documented somewhere in its docs but not in R's?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien It is documentation, perhaps not in the most readable manner.  Added relevant snippets from the docs to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This will work for any punctuation characters you could potentially have there

```
gsub("(^|[[:punct:]])([[:alpha:]])", "\\1\\U\\2", lastname, perl=TRUE)

##[1] "Wortmann-Kool" "Mulder"        "Nistelrooij"   "Camp"         
##[5] "Schaake"       "Veld"          "Lange"         "Oomen-Ruijten"
```

This will work only for hyphens

```
gsub("(^|-)([[:alpha:]])", "\\1\\U\\2", lastname, perl=TRUE)

##[1] "Wortmann-Kool" "Mulder"        "Nistelrooij"   "Camp"         
##[5] "Schaake"       "Veld"          "Lange"         "Oomen-Ruijten"
```